# YAML::Load(contents) issue with the gets method

Tags: ruby, load, yaml

I have a file named 'contents.txt' with YAML-formatted text inside of it.

I pass it in on the command line as `ruby Minesweeper.rb contents.txt`

Then, I have a load function:

```
def self.load
  grid = YAML::load(File.open(ARGV[0]))
  grid
end
```

Within my main `play` loop, I take an input from the user with the command `input = gets.chomp`

The issue is that before I can take any input from the user I get an error, because the input is not getting anything from the user. Instead, it is getting every line of the file and running through the loop, until of course the error occurs because my code isn't configured to run random inputs, such as those from the file.

Is this some side effect of `YAML::load` that I'm unaware of? How could I get past this?

Comment: I think you spelled File incorrectly

Comment: @MattDressel Ah, apologies. It is typed correctly in my program.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the things in Ruby that look like plain old functions are actually methods from `Kernel`, in particular, when you say `s = gets` you're actually calling `Kernel#gets`. From the [fine `Kernel` manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets):

> **gets(sep=$/) → string or nil**
>   **gets(limit) → string or nil**
>   **gets(sep,limit) → string or nil**
>
> Returns (and assigns to `$_`) the next line from the list of files in `ARGV` (or `$*`), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line.

So `gets` (without being inside an [`IO`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-gets) instance) will read from files mentioned on the command line by design. This is done to make it easier to write command line filters and one-off `ruby -e` scripts easier, for example you can say `grep pancakes` to search a file just `grep` to search the standard input.

If you want to read from the standard input then you should say so:

```
input = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @mu-is-too-short's answer,  you probably need to tweak your code a bit.

Are you sure you want `self.load` to be a class method?  I don't think `ARGV[0]` will be available in that context.

I believe you want [File.read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-read) (aka, IO.read), rather that [File.open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-open) which will just give you a `File` instance.  You would subsequently need to call `file.read`.

```
require 'yaml'

class Runner
  attr_reader :file_name

  def initialize(file_name)
    @file_name = file_name
  end

  def load
    file = File.read(file_name)
    ::YAML::load(file)
  end
end

Runner.new(ARGV[0]).load
```